# VirtualBox, macOS, Ubuntu guest screen flickering red

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using a 27-inch Mac with Sierra installed.  I have VirtualBox 5.1.26 (with guest additions) with an Ubuntu 16.04.3 VM.

When I run it full-screen with 3D acceleration activated, there is a serious problem of open applications on the guest flickering bright red flashes, especially in graphics programs, like Blender.

Without 3D, it's fine, but with clunky movements that are tolerable enough.

I've read about black flickers for guests, but red is new to me.  Is there anything I can do?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that my hardware is:

```
iMac 27-inch 2011 (macOS Sierra 10.12.5)
3.4 GHz Intel Core i7
8GB RAM
AMD Radeon HD 6970M 1024MB
```

**One more edit:** It appears that the problem is pretty much confined to Blender. All the tools flicker in and out, replaced by a solid red color.  Scrolling makes it worse.  Maybe I should use Blender in the host, but it would be cool to use it in Ubuntu.

Comment: IIRC 3D acceleration in guests is still very much experimental in VirtualBox.

Comment: Is there an accelerator that isn't experimental?

Comment: VMware Workstation’s is pretty good, it allowed me to run UT99 with almost no glitches. It hasn’t been considered experimental for a few years.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, VMWare has better options. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best technical solutions are thus:

VMWare Workstation or Fusion (Fusion works on Mac) or a [full dual-boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQIaDO9nR6Y), which is what I decided to do.  Works pretty well now.